# Option value from select statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to be able to have a select statement that lists everything from my category table.

Then once a option has been picked it assigns that option value to what I selected. Allowing me to add it to my table.

Currently my option value is set to `/"cleaner"/` I obviously don't want that as it's a static option. I've tried setting the option value to `$['articleCategory']` but that gives me some whitespace error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
                        $category = $pdo->query('SELECT articleCategory FROM Category');

                        foreach ($category as $row) {

                        echo "<option value=\"Cleaner\">" . $row['articleCategory'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>

                    </td>
```

Comment: What whitespace error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($category as $row) {

   echo "<option value=".$row['articleCategory'].">" . $row['articleCategory'] . "</option>";
}
```

welcome.

Comment: This don't throw any errors, It however doesn't add the updated text to the column. *Edit* Silly error my bad, Thank you :)